# GraphQL Query Component giving no results or errors

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I've been using graphql HOC for a little bit with not much issue but I'm trying to start using the new `<Query />` component but ma having an issue. I'm following the docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html) but I'm not getting any results. I know I'm requesting more in the gql query than I'm looking to display but, for now, I'm just trying to display as little as possible so that I know it works. Right now when the code is run I don't get the `<ActivityIndicator />`, I don't get an error, I just get a blank space where the data should be going.

My entire code in this component is below. Can anyone see any reason why I'm coming up with nothing? I'm running this query (minus the `User($id String!)` part and passing in an actual id) through the graph.cool playground and it's spitting out the data that I expect.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Icon, Button } from 'native-base';
import { withApollo, Query } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

import theme from '../../styles/theme';
import KoviHeader from '../../layout/KoviHeader';
import FooterTabs from '../../layout/FooterTabs';
import { signOut } from '../user/loginUtils';

const GET_USER_DETAILS = gql`
    query User($id: String!){
        user(id: $id) {
            id
            propertyNotes {
                title
                body
                property {
                    id
                    propertyName
                    createdAt
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {

        const { screenProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>
                <KoviHeader
                    title='Dashboard'
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                />

            <Content>

                <Query query={GET_USER_DETAILS} variables={{id: screenProps.user.id}}>
                    {({ loading, error, data }) => {

                        if (loading) return <ActivityIndicator size="large" />;
                        if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

                        return (
                            <View>
                                {data.user.map(u => {
                                    <Text>{u.id}</Text>
                                })}
                            </View>
                        )
                    }

                    }
                </Query>

                <Button
                    full
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => {
                        signOut()
                        this.props.client.resetStore();
                        }
                    }
                >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Logout</Text>
                </Button>
            </Content>

                <FooterTabs
                    activeBtn='dashboard'
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                />
        </Container>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: theme.COLOR_ORANGE,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
})

export default withApollo(Dashboard);
```

Comment: what are you getting as response ?

Comment: I’m getting nothing, no error, no loading, no data.

Comment: Did you check in the network of the browser what is the response

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to check the network in a React Native app, is there?

Comment: So I just realized that I have a type of `String!` in the setting of the `$id` parameter when it should be `ID!`. It's always something small like that isn't it?!? Thanks for the help anyway @aravind_reddy

Comment: Lol finally you figured it out anyways.